# Best practice for API Request's Queue

Tags: ios, swift, api, optimistic-locking

What is the best practice for Swift to make an API Request's queue? I mean, while there is more than 1 API being called on a function, how to make sure the first API is getting any response first then the second API is executed?

```
func test() {
    getAPI1()
    getAPI2()
}

func getAPI1() {
    Connector.sharedInstance().getAPI1({ (
        data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    })
}

...
```

I am thinking of giving a flag to indicate that there is any other API is still waiting for response so the second API that will be executed will be waiting until the flag is changed by the previously called API. But, is there any other better options? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps have your function dispatch to a queue? Check out the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1). In any case note that dispatch queues are first-in, first-out whereas operation queues are not.

Comment: You can also use dispatch groups. They often work better when you need to dispatch asynchronous functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost every Cocoa API works asynchronously, for example

Create an enum with a generic `Success` type

```
enum Result<T> : ErrorType {
  case Success(T)
  case Failure(NSError)
}
```

`getAPI1` returns an `NSData` object on success otherwise `NSError`

```
func getAPI1(completion:Result<NSData> -> ()) {
  var data : NSData?
  //
  if data != nil {
    completion(.Success(data!))
  } else {
    let error = NSError(domain: "my.domain", code: 9999, userInfo: [:])
    completion(.Failure(error))
  }
}
```

`getAPI2` has an `NSData` parameter and returns a dictionary `[String:AnyObject]` object on success otherwise `NSError`

```
func getAPI2(data:NSData, completion:Result<[String:AnyObject]> -> ()) {
  //
  completion(.Success([String:AnyObject]()))
}
```

`test` executes both methods asynchronously depending on their results

```
func test() {
  getAPI1 { (result1) in
    switch result1 {
    case .Success(let data) :
      getAPI2(data) { (result2) in
        switch result2 {
        case .Success(let dictionary) :
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            // update UI with the dictionary
          }
        case .Failure(let error) : print(error)
        }
      }

    case .Failure(let error) : print(error)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Paulw11 has stated, `dispatch_groups` will work in your case

```
dispatch_group_t myGroup = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_enter(myGroup);
[asyncMethodWithCompletion:^(id *results, NSError* error){
    // process results
    dispatch_group_leave(myGroup);
}];

dispatch_group_notify(myGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    // This will be called when asyncMethodWithCompletion is completed
});
```